# React.js app is opened as a blank page in the server, while it works well locally

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

When I run my React.js front-end locally using `npm start`, then it runs well. When I try to run it in the server using `npm install` and then `nom start`, then the blank page appears.

I checked the `public` folder and it has the following content in `index.html`:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-akgkshgfs"
crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div id="root"></div>
```

In `package.json` I use `http-server -a XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -p 55000`:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "http-server -a XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -p 55000",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

while locally I use:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

It works well in `localhost:3000`, but in the server the page is blank in `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:55000`.
It looks like I missed some installation step.

Any ideas? (it's the first time when I work with React.js and Node).

Comment: @JackO'neill: No, absolutely nothing. No error, no output.

Comment: did you build the page locally and then copy the build-dir or did you just publish your whole project to your server?

Comment: I copied the project to the server without "node_modules". Then I executed `npm install` and `npm install http-server` in the server. Then `npm run-script build`. I got the message `The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json`. Finally I did `npm start` and got this: Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:55001
  http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:55001
  http://XXX.XX.X.X:55001

Comment: you can build it on the local machine and then only deploy your build, but it should also work this way, but you have to specify the build-folder as entry-point for http-server. so change your start script to `"start": "http-server ./build -a XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -p 55000",`

Comment: @JackO'neill Cool, now it works. Thanks.

Comment: @JackO'neill: Can you please publish you answer and also explain how to generate the production version locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http-server` uses `./public` as the default entry point for a website if nothing is specified ([docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)).

As you mentioned in the comments, you build your project on the server, so your bundled project is inside `/build`. So http-server has no content to show.

To display that site, you have to change your start script from

```
"start": "http-server -a XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -p 55000",
```

to

```
"start": "http-server /build -a XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -p 55000",
```

--

As mentioned in the comments, its better to build your production site locally and only deploy the bundled code.
Have a look at the following article for more information about better deployment:

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment